# LIMIT records with JOIN ... LIMIT on the parent not applied to child row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've to apply pagination to my data . I fetch my data through a complex join query do not have any sub query only simple joins.

Asssume this query [this is very simple query i have query which is complex then this]

```
SELECT 
   states.states_name , 
   countries.countrty_name , 
   states.state_id , 
   countries.country_id 
FROM  countries 
INNER JOIN   states ON     countries.country_id =  states.country_id
WHERE  countries.status = "1"  AND  states.status = "1"
```

here there can be chance states will be varying to the different countries.
Means USA can have 30 states, INDIA  can have 26 states, PAKISTAN can have 15 states....

**WHAT I WANT** 
now i want to query in a way that if i want to get data for top 5 countries for first time... again for another five means LIMIT 5,10 .... after that another 5 countries.

If you got my problem then any idea ....?? how it can be achieved...?? or not achievable through MySQL ??

means limit only parent ... do not limit childs...

Example

```
Countries    No of states
  USA            30
  INDIA          25
  UK             10
  FRANCE         18  
  CHINA          48     // so for the first time it will return this much rows [SUM OF THIS 5 COUNTRIES row]  ...  but only top 5 country 


  JAPAN          11
  UKRAINE        05
  RUSSIA         70
  GERMANY        10 
  SPAIN          06   // so for the second time it will return this much rows [SUM OF THIS 5 COUNTRIES row]  ...  but only seconmd top 5 country 


  ARGENTINA      03
  BRAZIL         23
  NORTH KOREA    14
  SOUTH KOREA    12  // so for the second time it will return this much rows [SUM OF THIS 5 COUNTRIES row]  ...  but only last top 5[available all if not 5] country 




 select    *
                         FROM saved_card sc
                         inner join redeem_code redeem On redeem.redeem_id = sc.redeem_id And redeem.status = '1'
                         inner join cards card On card.card_id = redeem.card_id And card.status = '1' And card.expiry_date >= '".$today."'
                         left join card_additional_info cinfo on cinfo.card_id = card.card_id And cinfo.status = '1'
                         where sc.user_id = '".$userId."'
                           And sc.status = '1'
                           And card.what_to_broadcast = '".$type."'
                           And redeem.used_coupon = '1'
                         ORDER BY redeem.redeem_id DESC, card.card_id ,cinfo.card_additional_info_id
```

Here one card have multiple saved_cards it will be per user and per redeem_coupon.
and one card will have multiple additional info.

I want data by saved_card... means there should be limit of 5 saved cards, and another 5 and anothr 5.....

In every saved_card [ It will have one to one connection to redeem_code] and connected to only one card [As card is parent] but can have multiple card_additional_info fileds [As parent is card and it can have multiple childs.]

Comment: Post the full sql, this should be achievable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try with a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    states.states_name, 
    countries.countrty_name, 
    states.state_id, 
    countries.country_id 
FROM
    countries 
INNER JOIN
    states ON countries.country_id =  states.country_id
WHERE
    countries.status = "1"
    AND states.status = "1"
    AND countries.country_id IN (
        SELECT country_id FROM countries LIMIT 5, 5)
```

Obviously, values for LIMIT will have to be replaced with your pagination logic.

Or if you want it like in the example you have provided:

```
SELECT 
    c.countrty_name, 
    COUNT(s.state_id) AS "states" 
FROM
    countries AS c
LEFT JOIN
    states AS s ON c.country_id =  s.country_id
WHERE
    c.status = "1"
    AND s.status = "1"
GROUP BY
    c.country_id
LIMIT
    5, 5
```

That should do it.

Comment: i had already think about it... this is the way i should follow... any other way ?